# Error compilando jsx con Browserify ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript, babel, browserify

Buenas,

Soy totalmente nuevo en el mundo de ReactJS. Estoy intentando hacer una app de prueba y me encuentro con lo siguiente.
Estos son mis archivos:

**BtnLink.jsx:**

```
    var BtnLink = new React.createClass({


    render : function(){
        return(
            <div>hola</div>
        )
    }
});
module.exports = BtnLink;
```

**index.js**

```
var Boton   = require('./components/BtnLink.jsx');

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("here with me");
        ReactDOM.render(<BtnLink>, document.getElementbyId('app'))
    },


    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Este código se encuentra en un archivo "BtnLink.jsx", el cual incluyo, en mi archivo index.js, conforme la documentación de browserify. Pero al momento de correr el comando para la compilación :

```
browserify js/src/index.js -o js/dist/index.js
```

La consola me dice que tengo un error en la línea "hola" del archivo BtnLink.jsx. Yo realmente no veo error, comprobándolo con todos los ejemplos de declaración. me parece que es bastante similar. ¿Alguien sabe que me falta? Muchas gracias.

Actualización: 
Actualicé los archivos, ahora aparte, estoy intentando correrlo con **babel** con este comando :

```
 babel --presets es2017 js/src/components --watch --out-dir js/dist/components
```

El resultado es el mismo, tanto con browserify como con babel me retorna que hay error en el hola
:

```
SyntaxError: js/src/components/BtnLink.jsx: Unexpected token (6:3)
  4 |   render : function(){
  5 |           return(
> 6 |                   <div>hola</div>
    |                   ^
  7 |           );
  8 |   }
  9 | });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa tu proyecto si agregaste los transformadores necesarios, [reactify](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify) o [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify), entre otras cosas estos se encargar de interpretar los fragmentos de código JSX, la linea donde te esta dando error es código JSX, también nos ayudaria que nos proporciones mas detalles como el error que te da y como esta configurado Browserify para poder descartar otros problemas.

Si no estas usando reactify o babelify, es recomendable usar babelify ya que reactify fue deprecado ya hace algún tiempo.

Con babelify debes agregar el preset ES2015 y react, luego usas de esta manera.

```
browserify script.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

en la documentación de los links encontraras mas detalles

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responderme. No me queda muy claro. debo usar alguna de esas dos librerias para poder luego correr el "browserify" ?

Comment: Utiliza babelify ya que reactify a sido descontinuado, me cuentas cómo te fue

Comment: Sinceramente, sigo sin comprender la falla he visto varios tutoriales y me dicen que debeira correrme sin problema. Allí completé los dos archivos, es algo simple, me parece quedebo estar ahogado en un vaso de agua.

Comment: Carlos, muchas gracias por responder. efectivamente el tema del babelify es. En principio no manejaba el funcionamiento y me fui a probar, como muestro ahora con *babel* directamente. Ahora te pregunto, uno puede integrar ese browserify y babelify al archivo ".babelrc" para que se ejecute siempre desde el comando de babel? lo digo xq ví que babel se  rompe igual al ejecutarlo, pero tiene un comando para que los archivos se actualicen automaticamente (watch) mientras q el browserify toca ejecutarlo por cada cambio. Gracias de antemano.